# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in SOAP web services in PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I am a beginner in Soap Web Services. I have looked over all the questions and answers related to mine but they have different scenarios and code and they don't seem to match with my requirement.

I am using a webservice created by a third party for product listing. I want to just fetch some data so that I may know the basic workflow of how Webservices work. Here is my current code

```
require_once('nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php');

$wsdl   = "http://ws.anchordistributors.com/anchorwebservice.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');

// Input params
$username = "mylogin_id";
$password = "mylogin_password";

// In this demo, we use json data , you can use any other data format for same
$json     = '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}';

$client->setCredentials($username, $password);
$error = $client->getError();

if ($error)
{
    echo $error; die();
}

$action = "GetCountries"; // webservice method name

$result = array();

if (isset($action))
{
    $result['response'] = $client->call($action, $json);
}

echo "<h3>Output : </h3>";
print_r ($result['response']);
echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
```

This is what I am getting back:

Output :

> Array ( [faultcode] => soap:Server [faultstring] =>
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. at
>   AnchorWebservice.AnchorWebservice.AuthenticateUser(String sFunction)
>   at AnchorWebservice.AnchorWebservice.GetCountries() --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- [detail] => ) Request
>
> POST /anchorwebservice.asmx HTTP/1.0 Host: ws.anchordistributors.com
>   User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) Content-Type: text/xml;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 SOAPAction:
>   "http://tempuri.org/AnchorWebservice/AnchorWebservice/GetCountries"
>   Authorization: Basic ODI1NjQ3OkVJTExDODI1 Content-Length: 401
>
> {"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}
>
> Response
>
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. Connection: close Date: Fri, 06
>   Oct 2017 18:47:28 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   X-AspNet-Version: 1.1.4322 Cache-Control: private Content-Type:
>   text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 744
>
> soap:Server
>         System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   AnchorWebservice.AnchorWebservice.AuthenticateUser(String sFunction)
>   at AnchorWebservice.AnchorWebservice.GetCountries()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

I have no idea why is this creating issue on what logic. Being a beginner I don't know the sense of the issue. I just want to be able to use `GetCountries` method to fetch the array of countries.

Comment: Try to consume the webservice unsing SoapUI. It can show the problem to you. The problem seems to be an error from the webservice, though. And last, usi PHP Soap instead of NuSoap.

Comment: i like the advice there aernt many answers so in the mean time i'll give soapUI a go

Comment: I agree with @GabrielHeming, use PHP's Soap http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Apart from that, your problem is that you are sending some example JSON string to the server, which is unable to process it. What happens if you remove `$json` from `$result['response'] = $client->call($action)`?

Comment: ya i removed the json but nothing happens,the error is the same and in the documentation they mentioned that an xml format security header is required for every call. how do i send and xml security header to the service?